# Is eating food before purchase in a supermarket considered stealing?

Tags: gezel-stealing

Would it be considered stealing by the Torah to take let’s say, chips from a grocery store, open it up and start eating it before you paid for it? I know this is a common thing that people do. Is it considered stealing by the rules of the Torah?  And if it is, is only Teshuva necessary because you obviously already paid for the food you ate? Thanks!

Comment: The Halachah here follows the accepted laws and regulations. Whatever is accepted by the local laws/specific store regulation is binding by the Halachah.